# NGINX get the filename without extension

Tags: nginx

how i can extract the filename without extension from
answer NGINX

i try this

`map $uri $basename  {  ~/(?<captured_basename>[^/]*)$ $captured_basename;  }`

but this get the filename with extension please help to slove this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
map $uri $basename {
    ~/(?<captured_basename>[^/.]+)(?:\.\w+)?$ $captured_basename;
}
```

- for extension-less URI `/example`, the base name will be `example`
- for `example.conf`, it will be `example` as well, etc.